# Setting a value from database in the conroller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to set the value of email value in the code below however I keep getting "undefined method `email=' ". current_user.email is based off of who is currently logged in. The log in system was made using devise. There will never be a time when someone can create a new post while not being logged in so there will always be a current_user.email value.

```
def create
    @post= Post.new(post_params)
    @post.email= current_user.email #this is the line where it falls apart
    if @post.save
        redirect_to posts_path, :notice => "Post Saved"
    else
        render "new"
    end
end
```

here is the posts table

```
class CreatePosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :posts do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.string :venmo_name
      t.float :price
      t.datetime :end_datetime
      t.integer :areacode
      t.string :email

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> undefined method `email='

It's saying that the setter method of `Post` for the `email` attribute is not defined. Your `posts` table is very likely just missing the column, otherwise AR would have generated it for you.

Comment: I posted my Post table

Comment: That's just a migration that's supposed to create the table. Did you run the migration? Make sure to check the actual *database* table. If you add columns to the migration after you've already run it, it will not have any effect.

Comment: Thank you! I just learned a lot about how to add new columns to databases

Comment: I'd vote up your answer but I don't have enough reputation to do so

Comment: @BelowAverageProgrammer No problem. Just make sure to check the tick under the votes counter to accept the answer. Thanks!